# Neo4j Cypher how to compute percentage of a relations attribute

Tags: neo4j, cypher

scenario as follows:
I have three types of nodes. A lecture is connected to N exams. Each exam is connected to X students.
The relationship between an exam and a student has a property that is either True or False.
My goal is to return the percentage of relationships with property value True for each lecture.

My current query is:

```
match(n:Exam)-[r:FROM]-(v:Lecture)
optional match (n)-[r2:WHO]-(s:Student)
return v.name,  count(r2) order by count(r2) desc
```

which returns the count of relationships between students and exams for each lecture.

Basically what I want is to combine these two queries to compute the percentage:

```
match(n:Exam)-[r:FROM]-(v:Lecture)
optional match (n)-[r2:WHO]-(s:Student)
return v.name,  count(r2) order by count(r2) desc
```

and

```
match(n:Exam)-[r:FROM]-(v:Lecture)
optional match (n)-[r2:WHO]-(s:Student)
where r2.PROPERTY = True
return v.name,  count(r2) order by count(r2) desc
```

Can anyone help me achieve this? I haven't been able to do this, every time I try to combine these two queries I either get the total amount or the amount with PROPERTY = True, but never both.
In SQL i would simply use both queries and combine them into one, but i have no idea how to do this in cypher.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your data model correctly, it is something like this:

```
(:Student)-[:WHO]-(:Exam)-[:FROM]-(:Lecture)

So, for your query, perhaps you could do something like this:
MATCH p=(:Student)-[r:WHO]-(:Exam)-[:FROM]-(v:Lecture) //we want the path of Student to Lecture
WHERE r.PROPERTY=True
RETURN v.name AS Name, count(r) AS Score ORDER BY Score DESC
```

One node I'd make, always include relationship directions in your query if known, they will speed up the performance